# per_page is not type of integer. Woocommerce REST API Node.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, react-native, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using Woocommerce rest api with react native. I am trying to get list of all categories but I am getting maximum 10 items.

```
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({url: "xxxxxs", // Your store URL 
ssl: true,
consumerKey: "xxxxx", // Your consumer secret
consumerSecret: "xxxxxx", // Your consumer secret
wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API
integration version: "wc/v3", // WooCommerce WP REST API version
queryStringAuth: true,})

const categories = await WooCommerce.get( "products/categories?per_page=50")
console.log(categories)
```

I am getting this response:

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same error. How did you manage to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters this way:

```
...
parameters = {}
parameters[per_page] = 1

categories = await WooCommerce.get("products/categories/", params=parameters)
```